# If all the characters are not combination of zero and special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

I have a textbox in which i have restricted user to input values other than alphanumeric key and slash with following

```
regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9/]+$/g;
```

so the user can't input the special character other than slash `/`.

Now there is a new scenario in which I don't want the user to input either of these combination:

- `0`
- `00/00/000/`
- `0////`
- `////`
- `000/000/`
- etc

The input size of the input text is `20`, so any length could be possible my concern is any characters other than `0` or `/` is valid.

These should be valid:

- `01/001/01/`
- `01`
- `1`
- `a1/12`
- `00/10/00/1`
- `1/1/1/1/00`
- `0/00/0`

Anything other than zero or slash in the input is valid. Even a single occurrence of alphabet or number greater than zero makes it valid.

Any help is highly appreciable. Regular Expressions are most welcomed.
Thanks well in advance.

Comment: Your last example of a valid input `0/00/0` seems to contradict the description? Is it only when the slash is at the end?

Comment: @whrrgarbl it's not the case, the characters can terminate anywhere in between one to twenty, doesn't matter if the ending character is zero or slash, their should be a tleast one non-zero number,or any alphabet

Comment: Okay, so... your last example should *not* actually match?

Comment: @whrrgarbl yeah you are right this is the case

Answer (score 0):

First, your anchor's in the wrong place, negating the characters you wish to allow:

```
regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9/]+$/g;
          ^
```

Move it here:

```
regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9/]+$/g;
         ^
```

Here's the solution. I've indicated what I added with "+":

```
regex = /^(?![0/]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9/]+$/g;
          ++++++++++
```

The `(?!foo)` pattern is known as a **negative lookahead**, which Javascript supports. It fails the match if the upcoming characters *do* match `foo`. Therefore if the upcoming characters are all zeroes or slashes, then the match will fail. And then it moves on to checking that all the characters are alphanumeric or the slash.

As @Mavericks noted though, I don't know what's going on with your last case, "0/00/0".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`regex = /(^[^a-zA-Z0-9/]+$)|(^[0/]+$)/g`

This simply adds a second match group at the end: `(^[0\/]+$)` to check if it is entirely 0 and slash.